# Use anonymous type in generic class

Tags: c#

I have the following class with an Add mapper

```
public class OrderMapper<T> {
  public OrderMapper<T> Add<TKey>(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> expression, String name) {
  }
}
```

which I use as follows:

```
OrderMapper<Post> mapper = new OrderMapper<Post>().Add(x => x.Created, "created");
```

The problem is that sometimes I have the following:

```
posts.SelectMany(x => x.Category, (Post, Category) => new { Post, Category });
```

Which returns a list of anonymous types:

```
var objects = new { Post post, Category category }
```

I am not sure how to create an OrderMapper of this type ...

I think maybe I need to change my class method to an extension like:

```
OrderMapper mapper = objects.Add(...).Add(...)
```

Could someone tell me the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Create` method for the `OrderMapper` class :

```
public class OrderMapper
{
    public static OrderMapper<T> CreateMapperFor<T>(IEnumerable<T> typeProvider)
    {
        return new OrderMapper<T>();
    }
}
```

And, use it as such :

```
var objects = Enumerable.Repeat(new { /* ... */ }, 1);
var mapper = OrderMapper.CreateMapperFor(objects)
    .Add(/*...*/)
    .Add(/*...*/);
```

Comment: Inside Add method I need to access the type of object and not the type of objects since objects is a list of object.

Comment: @MiguelMoura Oops! I've updated my answer to fix it.